# Expression in datatable appends data instead of adding

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, expression

I have a datatable with a few columns .
I am trying to add the column values using the datacolumn.expression.
The columns used for adding is of type decimal. Also the calculated column is also decimal. But while processing the expression, (like datatable column1+ datatable column2) its just appending the data.

```
SlNo Name F1 F2 F3
1     A    1  2  3
2     B    3  4  5
```

I am expecting an output similar to this.

```
SlNo Name F1 F2 F3 Total
1     A    1  2  3  6
2     B    3  4  5  12
```

What I tried.

```
dtTempData.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(Decimal));           
dtTempData.Columns["Total"].Expression = "[F1]+[F2]+[F3]";
```

Now the output I am getting is in the following way

```
123
345
```

its just appending the data.Thanks in advance of any help.

Comment: Make sure F1,F2,F3 columns are of numeric types. Check this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior if just one of the source columns is of type string.

Comment: I should rectify. If the first or second column are of type string. if the third column is of type string the output will be different (33, 75)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening.

```
dtTempData.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(Decimal));
dtTempData.Columns["Total"].DefaultValue = 0;
dtTempData.Columns["Total"].Expression = expression;
```

This is the way I created the columns, but while performing suming based on expression, it appends the data.
I am importing data from another datatable which is type of string. So I tried to convert the data by using the following manner.

```
 string expression="Convert(F1, 'System.Decimal') + Convert(F2, 
'System.Decimal') + Convert(F3, 'System.Decimal')"
```

Now this is working and the Total column is having the value after addition. Thanks all for your help.